# Access post from post id in URL

Tags: posts, urls, unit-tests

I'm doing unit tests for my plugin, and in my unit test, I check some basic things such as posting a custom post type. My script can create new post, and I can retrieve the ID of the posted item (I'm redirected to an URL like `http://wordpress.loc/wp-admin/post.php?post=16&action=edit&message=6`, so I can deduce that the new post has the ID 16).

From this ID, I'd like to check if the post is as it should be by accessing it via URL, with something like `http://wordpress.loc/?post=16`, but I can't find a way to get directly to my new post using just the ID and without doing any PHP stuff.

Is that possible?

Comment: Use your `?your-custom-post-type=16`

Comment: Nope, it returns a 404.... Maybe it would be easier to modify my function.php to do that

Comment: OK, try `?p=16`.

Comment: Ok ok you got it... Why an answer to such basic question is so hard to find? Spent more than half an hour googleing around... Anyway! Thanks!

Comment: @AlexandreGermain "Thank you" shouldn't be part of question, answer or comment. That's why I removed that in my edit.  Reference: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Post can be accessed using post id by passing it as `page_id` query param to `index.php`. e.g.

```
http://wordpress.loc/index.php?page_id=16
```

Or simply

```
http://wordpress.loc/?page_id=16
```